# Convert time by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, chromeless

From the youtube player http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player I get a time value in seconds, like '243.577'. Let it be a simple string.

How do I convert it to the value like: '04:35'?
Like 4 minutes and 35 seconds (hope I made right calculations) for this example.

If the value is just 5 seconds, then it should give something like '00:05'. If negative, then '00:00'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var raw = "-54";

var time = parseInt(raw,10);
time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;

var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
var seconds = time % 60;

minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0"+seconds : seconds;

alert(minutes+":"+seconds);
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8zPRF/

**UPDATE**

Some added lines for negative numbers and string format:
http://jsfiddle.net/8zPRF/3/

Comment: for -54 it gives -1:-54, it would be perfect, if you fix that

Comment: This is great, but you should be doing either "minutes <= 9" or "minutes < 10". As it is, 0-8 have a zero added to them, 9 drops to a single digit. Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
```

You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: once you have a date object, you can format it any way you want.

Comment: if I know how to do that, I would not ask

Answer (score 0):

I find the [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library extremely helpful when dealing with dates. It extends the built in javascript Date object.

E.g.

```
var timeString = new Date(seconds * 1000).toString('mm:ss');
```